# Android Emulator says "...App isn't responding"

Tags: android-emulator, maui

After displaying a new Dialog (actually it is a ContentView) my Android Emulator says "...App isn't responding" with a "Close App"- and a "Wait"-Button.

Is this probably something I screwed up or is this an Emulator related issue? Is there anything I can do to prevent or fix this?

I am a bit affraid that is my fault with something I did not handle correctly so that the App runs into issues on the real device not just the emulator.

I am working with VS 2022 and the "Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)" Emulator started in Debug of VS.

Any hints?

Comment: Do you add breakpoints in debugging? If so, don't mind this and just click "Wait". If it's ok, could you provide some code so that I can reproduce your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My app was very simple and it worked on physical devices without any problems. But on an emulator, I was receiving this message every couple of seconds ("App isn't responding").

My emulator was set to have only 1 GB of RAM. I increased the amount to 2GB and the problem disappeared. I was emulating Pixel 5 with API 33.

Answer (score 3):

This can happen even if your code is good. Once it happens, its likely to keep happening.

- After you click "Wait", are you able to interact with the dialog? If so, then its likely just emulator has gotten messed up.

Fixes to try:
(1) Delete app from emulator, download it again. This helps ensure a clean start.
(2) IF still happening, Use Tools / Android / Android Device Manager. Select emulator, Stop it if running, do "Reset to Defaults" (just clears some internal settings) or "Factory Reset" (completely resets device to original factory condition). Quit and Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Restarting studio did it for me. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

There is also another possible source of this issue. A very serious one.
If you start receiving this - you need to check that

- all the code that interacts with UI is doing it on the UI thread.
- all objects that are passed to methods of the UI elements you are
  calling are created on the UI thread as well.

Otherwise your UI will become unresponsive at some point and there'll be trouble. MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread is your frined here

Also another important thing is avoiding setting control properties manually and instead using bindings wherever possible.